# ListView with AsyncTask don't work

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I want display in my android application a ListView. This ListView contains two things : a title and an image.

Do display the title and the image, I call my dataBase MySQL with Php. The Php code send me a JSONObject. I use the json to display the both informations in my ListView.

The problem is that I have an error of AsyncTask and a NullPointerException when I run my project and I don't understand why.

So I give you my code and I hope that you can help me.

ListViewMovies.java

```
      public class ListViewMovies extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

//php server
private static final String MOVIES_URL = "http://10.0.0.35/BD_Internet_Security_Movies/list_movies.php";

// variables
ListView listview;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
public JSONArray jsonarray;
//String mail ="null";

static String TITLE = "title";
static String IMAGE = "image";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_liste_view_movies);

    // Execute AttemptListMovie AsyncTask
    new AttemptListMovie().execute();

}

class AttemptListMovie extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     */
    // boolean failure = false;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListViewMovies.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting for List of movies...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        /*List<NameValuePair> args = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        args.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mail", mail));*/

        //Use php to create the JSONObject that we want
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(MOVIES_URL);

       // Log.d("json : ", json.toString());

        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("ListMovies");

            // checking  log for json response
          //  Log.d("JsonArray : ", jsonarray.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Choose elem in the JSON Objects
                map.put("title", jsonobject.getString("title"));
                map.put("image", jsonobject.getString("image"));

                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the listView in listViewMovies.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(ListViewMovies.this, arraylist);
        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the pDialog
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Now my JSONParser.java

```
    public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jsonObj ;
static String json = "";

// default no argument constructor for jsonparser class
public JSONParser() {

}


public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jsonObj;

}
```

My ListeViewAdapter to display in the listView each elem in each item

```
    public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
ImageLoader imageLoader;


public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;
}

/* Permet de savoir le nombre d'item à afficher dans le liste view */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView title;
    ImageView image;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_view_adapter, parent, false);
    // Get the position
    resultp = data.get(position);

    // Locate the TextView in listView.xml
    title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    // Locate the ImageView in listeView.xml
    image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
    title.setText(resultp.get(ListViewMovies.TITLE));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(ListViewMovies.IMAGE), image);

    return itemView;
}
```

}

And to finish, my php code

```
    <?php

    include ('config.php');

 // query the application data
 $query = $handler->prepare('select title, image from Movies');

 //execute the prepared statement
 $query->execute();

 // an array to save the application data
 $result = array();
// iterate to query result and add every rows into array
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result["ListMovies"][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($result);
exit;

 ?>
```

And my error in the logcat :

```
        03-19 14:27:17.823  14263-14626/com.enterprisemobility.michael.ca2enterprisemobilitymysqlkozamichael E/Buffer Error﹕ Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
03-19 14:27:17.823  14263-14626/com.enterprisemobility.michael.ca2enterprisemobilitymysqlkozamichael E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
03-19 14:27:17.827  14263-14626/com.enterprisemobility.michael.ca2enterprisemobilitymysqlkozamichael E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.enterprisemobility.michael.ca2enterprisemobilitymysqlkozamichael, PID: 14263
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.enterprisemobility.michael.ca2enterprisemobilitymysqlkozamichael.ListViewMovies$AttemptListMovie.doInBackground(ListViewMovies.java:82)
            at com.enterprisemobility.michael.ca2enterprisemobilitymysqlkozamichael.ListViewMovies$AttemptListMovie.doInBackground(ListViewMovies.java:49)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-19 14:27:18.167  14263-14318/com.enterprisemobility.michael.ca2enterprisemobilitymysqlkozamichael D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xaf13f400 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xafd17aa0
03-19 14:27:18.270  14263-14263/com.enterprisemobility.michael.ca2enterprisemobilitymysqlkozamichael E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.enterprisemobility.michael.ca2enterprisemobilitymysqlkozamichael.ListViewMovies has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{19504f24 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,348} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
            at com.enterprisemobility.michael.ca2enterprisemobilitymysqlkozamichael.ListViewMovies$AttemptListMovie.onPreExecute(ListViewMovies.java:62)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at com.enterprisemobility.michael.ca2enterprisemobilitymysqlkozamichael.ListViewMovies.onCreate(ListViewMovies.java:45)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Michaël

Comment: Right from your logs, your JSONObject "json" handled in your "AttemptListMovie" AsyncTask is null.

Comment: Indeed, when I use the debbug mode, json = null. But why when I test my php code in the localhost, I have a json result not null. I use yet the good URL in my java code. So I don't undersatnd my error.

Comment: Step through or log and see what response you're getting.

Comment: Yet when I execute the php code in the localhost, I obtain this :

{"ListMovies":[{"title":"The Lord of the rings : The fellowship of the rings","image":"LOAD_FILE(\"\/home\/michael\/Documents\/Dkit\/Master1\/Semester2\/Enterprise_Mobility\/CA2\/images\/LoR1.jpeg\")"}]}

So why the json is empty ???

Comment: So your problem is in your JSONParser class that return null value. Can you add logs to see your httpResponse, your inputStream and your StringBuilder in your parsing job pls ?

Comment: I have change my JSONParser and now it's OK. However I don't know why before it's not work. Thank you for your help.